# function returns value before assigning a value from event listener

Tags: javascript, frontend, javascript-objects, web-frontend

I have the below code in which we are using a plugin in the code to send the file from attachments. However, the below code ".before" will intercept the code and allow us to make changes to the data before sending the file. Basically its a interception of code prior to sending the file. In my case, i'm opening a dialog box with send and cancel buttons and the ".before" function should return the data only when either of the "send" or "cancel" button gets clicked.

```
      Plugin.before("Service.sendFile", function (data) { 
      let s;
      document.querySelector('.x-body').insertAdjacentHTML(
        'afterbegin',
        `<div id="myDialog">
        <p>Are you sure you want to continue?</p>
        <img id="selectedImage" width="250" height="250"/><br><br> 
        <button id = "send_button" class = "sendButton">Send</button> 
        <button id = "cancel_button" class="cancelButton">Cancel</button>
        </div>`     
      )
      var image = document.getElementById("browse_file").files[0];
      var imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(image);
      document.getElementById("selectedImage").src = imageUrl;

      document.getElementById("send_button").addEventListener("click", function() {
        console.log("User clicked Send");
        document.getElementById("myDialog").style.display = "none"
        s = true;
      });

      document.getElementById("cancel_button").addEventListener("click", function() {
        console.log("User clicked Cancel");
        document.getElementById("myDialog").style.display = "none"
        s = false;
      });

      return s ? data : null;
    });
```

//Promise approach

```
function customConfirm(message) {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var result = false;
            document.querySelector('.cx-body').insertAdjacentHTML(
              'afterbegin',
              `<div id="myDialog">
              <p>${message}</p>
               <img id="selectedImage" width="250" height="250"/><br><br> 
               <p>Are you sure you want to attach the image?</p> 
               <button id = "send_button" class = "sendButton">Send</button> 
               <button id = "cancel_button" class="cancelButton">Cancel</button>
              </div>`     
              )
  
            document.getElementById("send_button").addEventListener("click", function() {
                console.log("User clicked OK");
                result = true;
                console.log("result", result);
                resolve(result);
            });
        
            document.getElementById("cancel_button").addEventListener("click", function() {
                console.log("User clicked Cancel");
                result = false;
                console.log("result", result);
                resolve(result);
            });
            var image = document.getElementById("cx_browse_file").files[0];
            var imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(image);
            document.getElementById("selectedImage").src = imageUrl;
          })
      }

      

       Plugin.before("Service.sendFile", async function (data) {   
        let conf = await customConfirm("Are you sure you want to continue?");
       

      if(conf){
         return data;
        }
      });
```

right now it just returns null as soon as I click on Attachment and select & open the image. I tried "Promise", "async/await" it did not work. It started throwing error saying it cannot read undefined properties of files. Help me to resolve this.

Comment: Your `customConfirm` returns a Promise, but you’re never awaiting any of the calls to this function. I don’t know if `Plugin.before` accepts an `async` function, but that should be the next step to try.

Comment: @SebastianSimon, apologies, please see the update code in the promise approach. When I write the async and await keyword, the custom function gets called, but when trying to read the files, it throws the error "unable to read the properties of undefined of files" in the console.

Comment: But this error seems entirely unrelated to your usage of Promises. Is the DOM loaded at the time `document.getElementById("cx_browse_file")` is executed? Is `document.getElementById("cx_browse_file") === null`? What is the exact error message? _“cannot read undefined properties of files”_ is not a concept in JavaScript. _“unable to read the properties of undefined”_ — If `file` _is_ the property that JS attempts to read, then this isn’t possible, because [`getElementById`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) will never return `undefined`; it might return `null`.

Comment: @SebastianSimon, the exact error from the "plugin.before" is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'files')" I get this error from the plugin side. But without async and await keyword, it does not throw this error. It reads the file correctly and displays it.